# How to return to original scroll position after submitting a form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I automatically scroll back to the position of the button after submitting my form?

```
function scrollToButtonPosition(x,y){
  window.scrollTo(x,y);
}
```

How do i call this function and pass the current scroll coordinates when i click the submit button?

Comment: after submitting your form, you will be loading a new (or reloading the same) page ... so, use cookies or locastorage or maybe send something in the submit and that gets sent back in the result of the form submit .. of course, I could be way off, seeing as there's no code to refer to

Comment: If you could make the request an ajax one then the page wont reload after form submit and scroll position will be maintained.

Comment: There is no need to reload the page after a form submit. Do it via ajax and you are safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options to achieve that.

- Use AJAX to submit the form to the script. Scroll position will be maintained
- On submit save the scroll position into local storage and on load look if this item is in local storage, if so scroll to it and delete item in local storage. If not, this page didn't get loaded due to form submission.
- Using `a` anchor. Submit form normally to script but append the anchor to the form action URL.

Using AJAX would be the best option. But appending an anchor is the easiest to implement.

Fiddle for the anchor: https://fiddle.jshell.net/vaxdu4n7/9/show/

Comment: Using localStorage for this could produce unexpected behavior if the user had the same page open in multiple tabs. sessionStorage would be safer in this respect.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm not sure why an user would open the same page in multiple tabs. But there are always 2 other options to use. :)